# Prevent VS2012 to convert my projects into Web Applications

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-application-project

We have a big solution that we just recently migrated to Visual Studio 2012. In this solution, one project is the main Web Application in IIS and the other projects are folders inside this Web Application. Every time we open the solution, VS2012 turns these folders into Web Applications and it breaks the site. Is there any way to avoid this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the solution. We changed the projects properties to not use IIS but a Custom Server with our local url.